# Apply a function whose result depends on the previous results to a numpy array

Tags: python, loops, numpy

I am trying to apply a custom function to a numpy array, and the result of the function depends on the previous result. Specifically, i'm trying to implement a low pass filter using the formula:

```
f(n) = f(n-1) + (a[n] - f(n-1)) * sampleRate / filterConst
```

I can, of course, keep a state variable for `f(n-1)` and loop over the entire array. I want to know if there's a proper way to do this, one that respects numpy conventions.

Also, i am sure that part of my problem is that i don't know what question to ask. So if you can at least point me in the right direction, that is greatly appreciated.

P.S: I am interested in a general solution for this. I understand there might be some already existing implementation of this low pass filter, and i would be interested in knowing about it, but what i need is a general way of implementing this type of function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just loop over the whole array just outputted the current index to the same index in a new container this should maintain your numpy conventions.

I don't know if it would be easier to do the low pass filter in fourier space and then just reverse fft? Although that depends on the data you are working on I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

def f(n): 
  return n*2

def reduce_func(n, a, sampleRate, filterConst):
  return f(n-1) + (a[n] - f(n-1)) * sampleRate / filterConst

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
data = np.array([12,34,56,78,90])
sampleRate = 0.5
filterConst = 1.5

reduce(reduce_func, a)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your equation.  I can refactor it.

```
res[n] = res[n-1]*(1-sampleRate/filterConst) + a*(sampleRate/filterConst)
```

the following is only quickly tested.  It's based on work I did projecting prices based on assumptions with both % and absolute changes over time.

```
import numpy as np

def do_filter(arr, sample_rate, filter_const, axis=-1):
"""  arr - a np array of floats your a
     sample_rate - a scalar
     filter_const - a scalar
     axis - int The axis to project along
"""  
    factor = sample_rate / filter_const
    cum_factor = np.full_like(arr, 1-factor).cumprod(axis=axis)
    # cum_factor is effectively a price index of factors
    amt = arr * factor / cum_factor
    # amt represents the values to add in deescalated by the price index.
    return amt.cumsum(axis=axis) * cum_factor
    # return the cumsum of the deescalated values in amt reescalated.
```

Having constructed this for prices I couldn't use it as my period on period factors could be zero. In which case it breaks down.  As you have the same period on period factors it possibly works for your case.

If sample_rate (or filter_const) are also arrays this can be tweaked to work with arrays too.